# how to pass user data to perl URI object

Tags: perl, web-scraping, uri, bugzilla

I'm trying to log in Bugzill through Perl URI and I was not able to pass
"Bugzilla_login=@mentor.com&Bugzilla_password= info.

I need to log in because after that I want to webscrape some data from bugzilla.

```
my $data = $scraper->scrape(
my $uri=URI->new('http://prdbugzilla.wv.mentorg.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22444')
);
```

I'm trying to do something like

```
curl --data "Bugzilla_login=USER&Bugzilla_password=PASSWORD"  http://prdbugzilla.wv.mentorg.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19971
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URI` just builds a URI object; it doesn't generate an HTTP request.  Try `LWP::UserAgent` and `HTTP::Requset` instead:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( POST => 'http://...' );
$req->content('Bugzilla_login=USER&Bugzilla_password=PASSWORD');
```

Then you can send the request using `LWP::UserAgent`.